# Palti son of Laish

Tags: samuel-shmuel-book-of

After David took Michal back, what happens to Palti? 
I feel so bad for him. He most probably grew to love her and then all of a sudden she was taken away from him...

Does he go on to marry somebody else or what?!

Comment: related https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/36596/759

Comment: Whatever happened to him afterwards, he obviously returned back home: וַיֵּלֶךְ אִתָּהּ אִישָׁהּ הָלוֹךְ וּבָכֹה אַחֲרֶיהָ עַד בַּחֻרִים וַיֹּאמֶר אֵלָיו אַבְנֵר לֵךְ שׁוּב וַיָּשֹׁב:

Comment: Maybe you could edit your post to include some more context? Perhaps you could describe the incident you're referring to, tell us who Palti is, and provide a citation to the section you're referring to? As it stands, I agree with the unclear VTC reason, but I disagree with whomever voted off-topic.