# What Ever Happened To Palti Ben Laish After He Returned Michal To King David?

Tags: king-david, malchut-royalty

Did he end up marrying someone else? I feel so bad for him that someone he loved so dearly was taken away from him after being teased. etc. I'm not condemning What King David did but hindsight he longer became intimate with her after she demeaned King David when he was dancing. (Or am I mistaken?)

It seems like King David should have let Palti and Michal be; He loved her so dearly.

Comment: Duplicate: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/83484/27180

Comment: @Shmuel In context, that means to look at the Gemara Sanhedrin.